# Using Tryparse to convert string to decimal in mvc.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have built an MVC.net page connected to sql table and I am using datatable on it. The table columns are something like, Customername, mobileNO,Icno,salary,transactiondate.

I have managed to get some search/filtering functionality so I can search by customerName or by mobile number but I cannot search by date or salry(decimal).

My front end search fields consist of search value : key in your search (string ) and search type : drop down list : icno, name, date.

Below is the code in my controller. How do I make it searchable by salary(decimal) and date as well.

I heard that I can use tryparse but I have no idea how to here. Salary is defined as decimal datatype in my class while transactiondate as DateTime datatype.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
{
     criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["SearchValue"] + "%"));                
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
{
     criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["Icno"] + "%"));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchValue"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fm["SearchType"]))
{
     criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like(fm["SearchType"], "%" + fm["MobileNo"] + "%"));
}
```

Comment: Well have you looked at the documentation for `decimal.TryParse`? Have you tried using it at all yet?

Comment: i've read about it but i have no idea how to apply it in this specific scenario , what should i parse ?im just confused still, totally new to whole c#

Comment: *Did you read the documentation? Did you try to even google for TryParse?* As it is the question doesn't make much sense - either you have a string which you want to convert, or you're actually asking how to write a SQL query and make a completely unrelated question. The code you posted doesn't seem related to either case

Comment: i have and its looks something like this public static bool TryParse(
 string s,
 out decimal result
)

Comment: i'm just not sure how to apply it right here in my case

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, im sorry for my silly question i know i'm just a beginner so you may want to bare with me, its a string and i should convert to decimal but i got confused how to write the logic ...well, seems like nobody can understand me...so i'll continue learning from the scratch ...thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To do this use `decimal.parse` or `decimal.TryParse`

```
var toConvert = "1.5";

var converted = decimal.Parse(toConvert);
```

If you where to do ( in a console application ) : `Console.WriteLine(converted);`
Result will be 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Convert.ToDecimal("stringValue").